# Bash Makefile update comments?

Tags: c, bash, makefile

I need to make a shellscript that updates the comments in the C source code files for a project. I also need to add a new target to the Makefile in order to update the version number in the Makefile itself. I'll receive an (unknown name) zip file, which will have several files in it (named: calcmarks.h, calcmarks.c, correlation.c, globals.c, readmarks.c). This is what I currently have but am very confused on how to make this work

```
unzip $1 
for file in calcmarks.h calcmarks.c correlation.c globals.c readmarks.c  
do                                                                                                                 
e=`grep -oP '(?<= version )[0-9]+' file`                                                                             
let f=$e+1                                                                                                           
sed "s/version $e,/version $f, /" file  | sed "s/released.*/released $(date)/" > file                                
done
```

I thought my shellscript would unzip the folder, and then for each of those files it will find the comment, replace the version number with the updated version number and then replace the old date with the current date, but it not working. I'm also uncertain about how I can make a new target in the Makefile to update the comment in the Makefile itself. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the line

```
sed "s/version $e,/version $f, /" file  | sed "s/released.*/released $(date)/" > file
```

because you are reading from the same file you are writing to. Because of the redirection you are emptying the file to write new contents at the same time you start reading.

This would fix that:

```
mv file file.bak
sed "s/version $e,/version $f, /" file.bak  | sed "s/released.*/released $(date)/" > file
rm file.bak
```

But this would be cleaner:

```
sed -i "s/version $e,/version $f, /; s/released.*/released $(date)/" file
```

Comment: Just for clarity it's technically the redirection at the end: `> file` that empties the file not the pipe command per se.  When you redirect (without appending) to a file that file is immediately truncated to 0 length, and since all commands in a pipeline are invoked in parallel the redirect truncates the file as the first `sed` is trying to read it.